# Avahi DNS Stack for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, dns, avahi

I would like to know if we have an [avahi api](http://avahi.org/download/doxygen/) for iphone side? Alternatively, can we implement avahi protocol in iphone?

The avahi API provides:

> avahi-core: 
>   an API for embedding a
>   complete mDNS/DNS-SD stack into your
>   software. This is intended for
>   developers of embedded appliances
>   only. We dissuade from using this API
>   in normal desktop applications since
>   it is not a good idea to run multiple
>   mDNS stacks simultaneously on the same
>   host.
>
> D-Bus API:  an extensive D-Bus
>   interface for browsing and registering
>   mDNS/DNS-SD
>   services using avahi-daemon. We
>   recommend using this API for software
>   written in any language other than C
>   (e.g. Python).
>
> avahi-client: 
>   a simplifying C wrapper around the D-Bus
>   API. We recommend using this API in C
>   or C++ progams. The D-Bus internals
>   are hidden completely.
>
> avahi-gobject:
>   an object-oriented C wrapper based on
>   GLib's GObject. We recommd using this
>   API for GNOME/Gtk programs.

Comment: In the future, when you ask about an non-standard API/library/etc, you should include a link to it so other's know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Avahi and Bonjour are basically the same thing, both implementing mDNS.

Check these two documents:

- [Introduction to NSNetServices and CFNetServices Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html)
- [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com)

The first introduces the iPhone equivalent of Avahi and the second one builds on top of that and also provides a way to talk to clients that you find.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, any POSIX compatible library can be included on the iPhone. However, you might not be able to get it past the app store screening.

A better question would be: why bother? What does avahi offer you that the iPhone API DNS handling does not?

If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish we could better advise you.